# How i can map Question to correct multiple choice answer in this python quiz program?

Tags: python

I created simple python quiz app in which i save Options , Answers and Question to Empty list. but when i start quiz my correct answers aren't mapped with Correct questions, I just append answer to list if there are options which are common in two questions but correct answer in one question and wrong answer in another question still it will show correct answer because it just check 'correct_answer' list and list is random, i am not getting idea how exactly i can map my questions to specific answer, please if anyone can help

```
import itertools

question_list = []
option_list = []
correct_answer = []


def main_content():
    score = 0
    main = '1. Add question \n2. Show question \n3. quiz \n4. Exit'
    print(main)


    a = input('enter the value:')
    int_a = int(a)


    if a == '1':
            b = int(input('How many questions you want:'))
            for x in range(b):
                question_list.append(input('Enter your question:'))
                o = input('Option A:')
                p = input('Option B:')
                m = input('Option C:')
                r = input('Option D:')
                q = 'A):{}\nB):{}\nC):{}\nD):{}'.format(o, p, m, r)
                option_list.append(q)
                correct_answer.append(input('Put your answer here:'))
            main_content()
    if a == '2':
        if len(question_list) == 0:
            print('There are no question')
        else:
            for question, choices in zip(question_list, option_list):
                print(question)
            main_content()
    if a == '3':
        if len(question_list) == 0:
            print('There are no question')
        else:
            for question, choices, correct_choice in zip(question_list, option_list, correct_answer):
                print(question)
                print(choices)
                user_answer = input('Enter your answer here:')
                if user_answer in correct_answer:
                    print("Correct")
                    score += 1
                    print(score, "out of", len(question_list),"that is", float(score / len(question_list)) * 100, "%")
                else:
                    print('False Answer')
                    print('Your score is', score, "out of", len(question_list), "that is", float(score / len(question_list)) * 100, "%")
            main_content()
    if a == '4':
        exit()
```

Comment: Don't combine the choices. Keep them as 4 separate strings in a list and keep the index of the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the

```
if user_answer in correct_answer
```

To

```
if user_answer == correct_choice
```

Corrent_answer is the list and correct_choice is the corrcet value.